# Execute two local socket servers simultaneously in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, dhcp

I'm trying to simulate a DHCP server as a university task. It's required to execute at least 2 servers (or more up to 255) since several clients will be sending messages to these servers using BROADCAST (that's where the limit of 'only' 255 servers comes from).

But when I'm trying to execute 2 servers in 2 different terminals in Ubuntu, the second server executed is rejected. I guess it's due to IP at the same localhost or whatever (I'm sorry but I don't know too much about communication protocols)

How can I run several servers on the same machine? Our teacher told us about using VMWare to run another Linux OS, and try to run both, but for me this solution is far away from my thoughts... I will post the server and client connection statements, although I don't know if there's a problem with the C statements, or the OS configuration, etc.

Server:

```
int sockfd, newsockfd, clilen, n;
struct sockaddr_in  cli_addr, serv_addr ;
char host_name[200];
int size = sizeof(struct DHCP);
char buffer[size];
struct MACIP *macip;

if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0)) < 0) {
    printf("server: can't open datagram socket\n");
    return -1;
}

serv_addr.sin_family        = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr   = htonl(0); 
serv_addr.sin_port          = htons(SERV_UDP_PORT);

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) <0) {
    printf("server: can't bind local address\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Client:

```
int sockfd, n, clilen;
struct sockaddr_in  serv_addr, cli_addr;
char serv_host_addr[30];
int size = sizeof(struct DHCP);
char buffer[size];  

printf("Dirección IP del servidor (a.b.c.d) => ");
gets(serv_host_addr);

if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("client: can't open datagram socket");
    return -1;
}

int opt=1;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST,&opt, sizeof(opt))<0) {
    perror("Error opcion socket");
    close(sockfd);
    return 1;
}

bzero((char *)&cli_addr,sizeof(cli_addr));
cli_addr.sin_family         = AF_INET;
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,sizeof(cli_addr)) < 0)  {
    perror("client: can't bind a port");
    return -1;
}

serv_addr.sin_family        = AF_INET;
inet_pton(AF_INET, serv_host_addr,&serv_addr.sin_addr);
//serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serv_host_addr);
serv_addr.sin_port          = htons(SERV_UDP_PORT);
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What are you really tring to achieve? Why do you want to run up to 255 (or more?) servers in parallel (on one machine?) each listening to it´s own ip address?

Answer (score 1):

Every instance of your UDP server must listen on another port. Key line in your code is this:

```
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERV_UDP_PORT);
```

Looks like you have the port number as a constant (`SERV_UDP_PORT`). To make multiple servers run at the same time you need another port for each one.

Probably best solution in your case is to have a command line argument that would define the port on which you start your server.

Each client needs to know which port (and address of course) to connect to as well. So make your client to accept similar command line argument.

Comment: Thank you very much, correcting me the original post, I was tired and stuck with my English :D
According to my problem, Do I have to set a new port for each server I run? and later passing that port number as a client argument? Do you mean that?

Comment: the SERV_UDP_PORT number is 666, so if I want to set a new port number apart from this, how could i do it? do i need to register a new UDP service with a different port? or what do i do?...

Thanks but i do not control very well network issues.

Comment: Sorry I mean SERV_UDP_PORT is 6666

Comment: Anyway I've been testing, and ok, I can run several servers changing the port number, but one client will broadcast only to one of the servers (the server which port number you pass to the client), and I don't want this, i want to run several servers in the same subnet, and when a client broadcast, all servers catch the message sent by the client.

Comment: On one machine there can be only one process (server) listening on one given port and one network interface (IP). So on 5 machines you can have 5 servers listening on the same port 6666 (if there is one network card in each of them). And they will all get the broadcast. If it's all on one computer it's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

To run multiple servers, they should listen on different ports on same network interface. You may get away by using two network interfaces (say wifi and ethernet) on same network with different ips.

Comment: Could you pass me some tutorial or explain how can i do this, I'm totally newbie in network issues... Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can't get in details right now, but first you need to connect to network using your wifi as well as a cable (ethernet). Then you should have two interfaces configured with different ips. See if there is info for binding to specific ip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146747/bind-to-a-specific-ip-in-c-for-ubuntu

Comment: I have configured the Ethernet and the WiFi interfaces, both with their own ips, and similar Broadcast address. So you now any way to execute one server running under the ethernet network and other one under wifi?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to set up `alias interfaces` on an existing interface. Such `alias interfaces` then get their own ip address each.

Using the loopback interface (`lo`), which typical has `127.0.0.1` assigned, such aliases to this interface could then be called `lo:0`, `lo:1` ... and would carry the ip addresses `127.0.0.2`, `127.0.0.3`, ....

For details on how to achieve this see `man ifconfig`.